# Swift : why Safari doesn't open?

Tags: ios, swift

I set up a button with the function loading OAuthSwift, when I click on it the breakpoint on the function goes well, but Safari doesn't start with the Dribbble authentification link.

What I have to do ?

**My Button**

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        func doOAuthDribbble(){
            let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
                consumerKey:    Dribbble["consumerKey"]!,
                consumerSecret: Dribbble["consumerSecret"]!,
                authorizeUrl:   "https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize",
                accessTokenUrl: "https://dribbble.com/oauth/token",
                responseType:   "code"
            )
            oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "dribs://oauth-callback/dribbble")!, scope: "public+write+comment+upload", state: "", success: {
                credential, response in


                // Get User
                var parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
                oauthswift.client.get("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/user?access_token=\(credential.oauth_token)", parameters: parameters,
                    success: {
                        data, response in
                        let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                        println(jsonDict)
                    }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                        println(error)
                })
                }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
            })
        }


   }
```

**the WebViewController**

```
class WebViewController: OAuthWebViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

var targetURL : NSURL = NSURL()
let webView : UIWebView = UIWebView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    self.webView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    loadAddressURL()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func setUrl(url: NSURL) {
    targetURL = url
}
func loadAddressURL() {
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
    self.webView.loadRequest(req)
}
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if (request.URL!.scheme == "dribs"){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: It seems like you're not calling anything in your button handler (the `loginButton` func). You're actually defining a `doAuthDribbble` function, but not calling it. My bet is that nothing is happening when you're tapping the button, right?

Comment: Nothing happens, the function works when I make a breakpoint, but it doesn't open Safari. What I missed ? Thanks a lot I'm beginning

Comment: What code is it that's supposed to open Safari?

Comment: Philip Mills : The WebViewController isn't it ? I use OAuthSwift, and it worked before I set up the button

Comment: I think you're not supposed to open it in Safari, but rather present it to the user from inside your app. The `WebViewController` you've shown us seems to be there for that purpose. Try to instantiate an instance of `WebViewController` and show it using `presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`, and see what happens? Reading the docs of your OAuth library might also help.